# Unable to get a Hidden element in ASP.NET 4 from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need help to find a hidden button in Javascript. I am using ASP.NET 4.

I can find a `"visible = True"` but when i try to find a hidden element it says object not found

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowAge() 
     {
    var elem = document.getElementById('MainContent_chbFilter');
        if (elem != null)
            alert("Found 1");
        else
            alert("Not Found 1");
    var elemc = document.getElementById('MainContent_txtMSISDN');
        if (elemc != null)
            alert("Found 4");
        else
            alert("Not Found 4");
    }
   </script>
```

I am using `asp:content`
Please help

Comment: Is the button actually rendered out to the page?

Comment: Can you show the HTML so we can see that there is such an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an element has been hidden serverside (I'm assuming this is what you've done), this means that it won't get rendered onto the page, which is why Javascript won't find it in the DOM.

What you want is to assign it a CSS class (.hidden, for example) with display:none. You can then revert it back to display:block through Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET when you hide an element it is not rendered in the HTML at all.  This is in contrast to using the `hidden` property in CSS, where the element is still there, just visually hidden.  If you want to "hide" it server-side, but still make it available in the DOM, you should add `style="display:none;"` in your ASPX.

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting `Visible=False` to an element in the server-side code than it won't render to the page, so the JavaScript won't be able to access it.